# Status 404 whenever deploying my site to github.com

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I am getting a failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404() index.jsx[1]

I am currently running vite to create the react-app
I performed a npm run build
I also performed a new install
I also created a new react-app with vite twice.
why is it that when I push my react app to github its not showing any pages.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Designo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/index.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
import React  from 'react'
import  ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

```
{
  "name": "designo",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "vite": "^5.1.0"
  }
}
```

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

I tried running the build, i tried updating the src path in index.html

Answer (score 1):

If "deploying site to github.com," referring to hosting your site on [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/), the root cause might lie in the base public path specified in `vite.config.js`.

You could try adjusting your Vite configuration as follows:

```js
export default defineConfig((config) => {
  return {
    plugins: [react()],
    base: config.mode === 'production' ? '/REPO_NAME' : undefined,
  }
})
```

For `/REPO_NAME`, if your repository's URL resembles `https://github.com/username/your-repo`, then the value should be `/your-repo`.

This adjustment is necessary because a GitHub page's URL typically follows the format `https://username.github.io/repo-name`. Not specifying the correct base path could result in the `index.html` searching for files with a relative path at `username.github.io`, rather than `username.github.io/your-repo`, thus leading to a 404 error.

Comment: I also create a simple react app and didn't upload it to github I received the same MIME/TYPE error expected javascript module instead got text/html. In the index.html file what should be the in the script tags for react ? module or text/javascript ?

Comment: Debugging would be easier with additional information. Could you kindly provide the `index.html` file generated by running `npm run build`?

Comment: the index.html is the first screen shot that I uploaded its there

Comment: I mean the one that's generated after running `npm run build`, the one that's in the `dist` folder. Usually it'll look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/Kxc7A5S.png). The content of the `dist` folder is the one to be used for your Github Pages branch, rather than the source code. By the way, can you try running `npm run build && npm run preview` to see if you're able to browse your website locally?